# Golang parse raw HTTP/2 response

Tags: http, go, http2

I have a specific case where I need to parse HTTP/2 response output into Go's `http.Response`. Response itself has default structure:

```
$ curl --include https://google.com

HTTP/2 301
location: https://www.google.com/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 11:08:39 GMT
expires: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 11:08:39 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
server: gws
content-length: 220

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

**Status and body itself doesn't matter, it's just an example.**

`http` library has function `ReadResponse(r *bufio.Reader, req *Request) (*Response, error)` which does exactly what I need, but it fails parsing HTTP/2 with `malformed HTTP version HTTP/2`, however it works fine for HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0. Also, after doing request with `http.DefaultClient.Do()` you can see that response's field `Proto` contains `HTTP/2.0`, which means that there is no problem with HTTP/2.

Any ideas how to parse this response?

Comment: http.ParseHTTPVersion func not parse `HTTP/2`.replace `HTTP/2` to `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/2.0` .

Comment: it won't parse `HTTP/2.0` as well, but `HTTP/1.1` does the trick, won't simply replacing version break something in more complex responses?

Comment: Only match the body prefix is `HTTP/2 `, and then replace the first 7 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, I got you, I am just asking is it just a matter of first 7 bytes? Aren't different HTTP versions has different response format, parsing rules, etc?

Comment: At present, there should only be problems with `HTTP/2`. The method parsing `HTTP/2` by the http.ParseHTTPVersion method causes a parsing failure and returns the error `malformed HTTP version HTTP/2`.

Comment: FTR: this is not a "raw" HTTP/2 response. HTTP/2 uses a stateful binary protocol, so the raw response isn't human-readable and often not even self-contained. This is curl's rendering of an HTTP/2 response that immitates HTTP/1.x.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion, the reason for the parse error is `http.ParseHTTPVersion` not parse `HTTP/2`, replace the prefix 7 bytes into `HTTP/2.0` to fix it, or provide pr support for `net/http` to parse `HTTP/2`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://google.com", nil)
    {
        resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(httpbody)), req)
        fmt.Println(resp, err)
        // err is malformed HTTP version "HTTP/2", because http.ParseHTTPVersion not parse "HTTP/2"
    }

    {
        body := bytes.NewBuffer(httpbody)
        prefix := make([]byte, 7)
        n, err := io.ReadFull(body, prefix)
        if err != nil {
            panic("handler err")
        }
        fmt.Println(n, err, string(prefix))
        if string(prefix[:n]) == "HTTP/2 " {
            // fix HTTP/2 proto
            resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(io.MultiReader(bytes.NewBufferString("HTTP/2.0 "), body)), req)
            fmt.Println(resp, err)
        } else {
            // other proto
            resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(io.MultiReader(bytes.NewBuffer(prefix[:n]), body)), req)
            fmt.Println(resp, err)
        }
    }
}

var httpbody = []byte(`HTTP/2 301
location: https://www.google.com/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 11:08:39 GMT
expires: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 11:08:39 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
server: gws
content-length: 220

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>`)
```

output:

```
Hello, playground
<nil> malformed HTTP version "HTTP/2"
7 <nil> HTTP/2 
&{301 301 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Cache-Control:[public, max-age=2592000] Content-Length:[220] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Mon, 15 Jun 2020 11:08:39 GMT] Expires:[Wed, 15 Jul 2020 11:08:39 GMT] Location:[https://www.google.com/] Server:[gws]] 0xc0000902c0 220 [] false false map[] 0xc0000f2000 <nil>} <nil>
```